# reflection representation of an arbitrary Coxeter group

Tags: coxeter-groups

A reflection group has a reflection representation in the natural sense. But what is the reflection representation for a Coxeter group if its simple roots cannot be regarded as reflections in the Euclidean space?

In [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.0791v2.pdf), the author says that this is Definition 1.5 in

> W. Soergel, Kazhdan-Lusztig-Polynome und unzerlegbare Bimoduln uber Polynomringen, J. Inst. Math. Jussieu 6 (2007), no. 3, 501–525.

But I don't have this paper and I can't read in German. Would anyone please give some help?

Comment: Did you check Bourbaki, "Lie groups and Lie algebras" chapters 4-6 (English translation)? If I remember correctly, they define representations to $O(p,q)$ for general finitely generated Coxeter groups and explain what a pseudo-orthogonal reflection means in this context. If it is not there, it should be in Jim Humphreis book on Coxeter groups.

Comment: @studiosus Thank you very much for the comment. _Lie groups and Lie algebras, chapters 4-6_ is due to be returned to the school library in a week. I will check it then.

Comment: Try also Humphreys book "Reflection groups and Coxeter groups" too. http://books.google.com/books/about/Reflection_Groups_and_Coxeter_Groups.html?id=ODfjmOeNLMUC

Comment: The definition in Soergel is:  "Sei $(W, S)$ ein Coxetersystem. Bezeichne $T \subset W$ die Menge aller ,,Spiegelungen“, d.h. die Menge aller Elemente von $W$, die zu Elementen von $S$ konjugiert sind.  Unter einer spiegelungstreuen Darstellung unseres Coxetersystems verstehen wir eine Darstellung $W \hookrightarrow GL(V)$ in einem endlichdimensionalen Vektorraum über einem Körper $k$ der Charakteristik $\operatorname{char} k \ne 2$ mit den folgenden Eigenschaften:

Comment: (1) Unsere Darstellung ist treu.
(2) Für $x ∈ W$ gilt $\dim(V/V^x) = 1$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $x ∈ T$. In Worten haben genau die Spiegelungen aus W eine Fixpunktmenge der Kodimension 1 in $V$."

Comment: My very poor German translates this loosely as:  "Let $(W, S)$ be a Coxeter system.  Let $T$ be the set of 'reflections', that is, the elements conjugate to $S$.  A reflection representation of such a system is a faithful representation in a finite-dimensional vector space over an odd-characteristic field for which the elements of $W$ whose fixed-point spaces in $V$ have codimension $1$ are precisely those in $T$."